# Android: Change wifi sleep policy programmatically?

Tags: android, wifi, sleep

I am making an app that relies on wifi while the phone screen is locked. However the user might set wifi to sleep when it is locked. Is there a way to disable this sleep policy programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will set the sleep policy to never:

```
private void setNeverSleepPolicy(){
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            int set = android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, set);
        }
```

Comment: this is now deprecated, any alternative?